# React, Context, and Session Storage: Navigation bar updates properly when logging in but not when logging out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigationbar, react-context, session-storage

I have two things I'd like to know: First my application's navigation bar does not properly update to the guest navbar when logging out, but does update to the user navbar when a nonadmin account logs into it. If I do a page refresh (F5) after logging out it does update back to the guest navbar but that defeats the purpose of this being an SPA (Single page application).

The second thing I'd like to know is that currently my application uses React Context and Session Storage for authentication but I only use the Session Storage to actually get the information for the navigation bar. The reasoning is because Session Storage actually keeps the information after a page refresh while React Context forgets it. Is it better practice to use Session Storage for user authentication in a React application or should I just use React Context?

auth.js:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

App.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from './context/auth';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

/* Begin Import Components */
import NavigationBar from "./components/navbar";
import Public from "./components/public-components/public";
/* End Import Components */

function App(props) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

  // Temporary for testing
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
  }, []);

  const setAuth = (data) => {
    if(data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', data.username);
        sessionStorage.setItem('isAdmin', data.isAdmin);
        setCurrentUser({username: data.username, isAdmin: data.isAdmin});
        console.log('Data in setAuth: ', data);
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', null);
        sessionStorage.setItem('isAdmin', null);
    }
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser: setAuth }}>
      <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <div className="container text-center">
          <Public />
          <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
        </div>
      </Router>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

navbar.js:

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navigation(props) {
    const username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    const isAdmin = sessionStorage.getItem('isAdmin');
    const styledNavLink = {
        textDecoration: "none",
        color: "#F5F5F5",
        marginLeft: "10px",
        marginTop: "5px"
    }
    const styledHeader = {
        textDecoration: "none",
        color: "#FFF",
        fontSize: "1.5em"
    }

    function adminNav() {
        return (
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#" style={styledNavLink}>Admin</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to={`/${username}`}>Welcome, {username}</Link>
                    <Link to="/logout" style={styledNavLink}>Log Out</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    function loggedInNav() {
        return (
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#" style={styledNavLink}>User</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to={`/${username}`} style={styledNavLink}>Welcome, {username}</Link>
                    <Link to="/logout" style={styledNavLink}>Log Out</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    function guestNav() {
        return(
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                    <Link to="#" style={styledNavLink}>Guest</Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Link to="/register" style={styledNavLink}>Register</Link>
                    <Link to="/login" style={styledNavLink}>Login</Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        )
    }

    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="md">
            <Container>
                <Link to="/" style={styledHeader}>Flaskagram</Link>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                {username !== 'null'
                ?
                    isAdmin === 'true'
                    ?
                    adminNav()
                : loggedInNav()
                : guestNav()
                }
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default Navigation;
```

login.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../../context/auth';
import { Col, Form, Row, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Login(props) {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const { setCurrentUser } = useAuth();

    let referer;
    if(props.location.state !== undefined) {
        referer = props.location.state.referer;
    } else {
        referer = "/";
    }

    function postLogin() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('email', email);
        formData.append('password', password);

        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.wrongPassword) {
                setIsError(true);
            } else {
                setCurrentUser({username: data.user.username, isAdmin: data.user.isAdmin});
                setLoggedIn(true);
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            setIsError(true);
        });;
    }

    if(loggedIn) {
        return <Redirect to={referer} />;
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <header>
                <h2>Login</h2>
            </header>
            <section>
                <Form>
                    <Row className="justify-content-sm-center">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor="email">Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                        controlid="email"
                                        type="email"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={e => {
                                            setEmail(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                        placeholder="Enter email"
                                        autoFocus
                                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="justify-content-sm-center">
                        <Form.Group as={Col} sm={{ span: 6 }}>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor="password">Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                        controlid="password"
                                        type="password"
                                        value={password}
                                        onChange={e => {
                                            setPassword(e.target.value);
                                        }}
                                        placeholder="Enter password"
                                        />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Button onClick={postLogin} variant="success">Login</Button>
                </Form>
            </section>
            <Link to="/register">Don't have an account?</Link>
            { isError &&<p>There was a problem logging in!</p> }
        </main>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

logout.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../../context/auth';

function Logout(props) {
  const [isLoggedIn, setisLoggedIn] = useState(true);
  const { setCurrentUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentUser();
    setisLoggedIn(false);
  }, [ setCurrentUser ]);

  if(!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
  }

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default Logout;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. The issue was in `setAuth()` in App.js. I wasn't updating the context when logging out (when `data` wasn't defined in the if/else statement) so the navbar remained in the logged in state because of it.

updated setAuth in App.js:

```
const setAuth = (data) => {
    if(data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('username', data.username);
        sessionStorage.setItem('isAdmin', data.isAdmin);
        setCurrentUser({username: data.username, isAdmin: data.isAdmin});
    } else {
      sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
      sessionStorage.removeItem('isAdmin');
      setCurrentUser();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When logout happens you need to remove the items, you set in `SessionStorage` as follows in `Logout` component.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../../context/auth';

function Logout(props) {
  const [isLoggedIn, setisLoggedIn] = useState(true);
  const { setCurrentUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentUser();
    /* remove session storage items */
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('isAdmin');
    setisLoggedIn(false);
  }, [ setCurrentUser ]);

  if(!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect to={"/"} />;
  }

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default Logout;
```

In your `navBar.js` file, to check whether `userName` is empty then use `!!userName` to check whether it's not `null` or `undefined`.

Therefore, update `return` in `Navigation` component of `navBar.js` file as follows.

```
    return (
        <Navbar bg="primary" variant="dark" expand="md">
            <Container>
                <Link to="/" style={styledHeader}>Flaskagram</Link>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                {!!username
                ?
                    isAdmin === 'true'
                    ?
                    adminNav()
                : loggedInNav()
                : guestNav()
                }
            </Container>
        </Navbar>
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately after I applied the two new lines of code, the problem still remained the same

Comment: Can you tell me which `navBar` it's showing when user logs out as you're saying in your issue ? I believe it should be either `adminNav` or `loggedInNav` ? And I found another issue in `Navigation` component as well.

Comment: Can you please check what I have updated and tell me if it's working or not ? And also tell me which `navBar` you're seeing when you logs out if the issue is still there.

Comment: I updated "username" in the return() section to "!!username", but I still have the same issue. When I first start logged out, the guest navbar appears and session storage is empty as intended. After I log in the page goes from the login page to the root page, the logged in navbar appears, session storage sets "username" to "user", and sets "isAdmin" to "false". When I logout, session storage emtpies and returns to the root page, but the logged in navbar remains unless I do a full page refresh. Only then will it update correctly again to the guest navbar

Comment: Found the problem. Look at the answer I posted below.